# Do I really need all these font types loaded for FontAwesome or just the WOFF2 type?

Tags: font-awesome, woff2

I'm looking at the FontAwesome path.less and it looks like it's loading a bunch of the same font but different types...

```css
/* FONT PATH
 * -------------------------- */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=@{fa-version}');
  src: url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=@{fa-version}') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=@{fa-version}') format('woff2'),
    url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=@{fa-version}') format('woff'),
    url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=@{fa-version}') format('truetype'),
    url('@{fa-font-path}/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=@{fa-version}#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
//  src: url('@{fa-font-path}/FontAwesome.otf') format('opentype'); // used when developing fonts
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Do I really need all these font types loaded for FontAwesome or just the WOFF2 type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't actually load all those file types. The browser will pick the best one and just load that file.

Woff2 coverage isn't great just yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=woff2. Some folks get by with regular woff only, but with Font Awesome you're getting broader coverage for free. No reason to remove the rest.

Comment: Thank you very much! and also for that Awesome font :-)

Comment: What about if you are bundling fontawesome in a native mobile app? Can you remove some of the formats to reduce the file size of the app without loosing compatibility?

Comment: For bundling you can import each partial file from the fa npm package, just like in font-awesome file, but skipping "path" and adding just the formats you want.

Answer (score 3):

In 2022+ you probably only need the **woff2** files. Browser support is now pretty good for woff2.

Woff2 files are better compressed than older font types. Woff2 fonts are compressed using **brotli** as part of the file format.

If you generate **critical Css** the references to those other font types could be taking up unnecessary space in your critical css.

caniuse.com can show you the browser support.

- EOT was for IE8 and below.
- TTF format was developed by Microsoft and
  Apple in the 1980s.
- WOFF was developed in 2009 and compresses the
  fonts.
- WOFF2 offers smaller file sizes and better performance for
  modern browsers.

**references**: CSS Tricks, caniuse.com, design.tutsplus.com